# Solutions to problem sheets

Tags: programming, automation

For writing problem sheets I have a customized theorem environment called `pr` for the problem and a specialcomment called `solution` for the solution. See example below. Now my question is, if it is possible to get *automatically* the following:

First page(s): Problem sheet without solutions
next page(s): Problem sheet with solution below each problem

I would strongly prefer solutions which don't use a special documentclass like `exam`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}%

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont%
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]%
    \hfill{\normalfont(##3)}\newline}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
  \theoremindent0cm
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newtheorem{pr}{Problem}

\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{solution}{\noindent\small Solution: }{\\\normalfont \normalsize}

%\excludecomment{solution}


\begin{document}

\begin{pr}
   Problem
\end{pr}

\begin{solution}
   Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{pr}
   Problem
\end{pr}

\begin{solution}
   Solution
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

Comment: For this feature you must store the contents of `pr` and `solution` in a separate savebox to use `pr` twice.

Comment: Regular TeX is an interpreted language and TeX engine buffers enough content for one paragraph before it makes tokenification and produces the content (actually if I recall correctly it has to pass five times to produce the finished product dvi file). I would be surprised it you could do above with out storing things as suggested. I am not aware that TeX can do goto statements (I am recently thinking of it as a general programming language) which could be used in a very ugly way to accomplish above.

Comment: @Predrag: I don't think anything in your first sentence is right.  TeX is a macro language, not interpreted (okay, a small distinction); it doesn't buffer at all, but interprets "as it goes", though it *does* produce paragraphs one at a time.  It also tokenizes the input as it goes, though you may be thinking that it does *line breaks* only after reading a whole paragraph (true).  It also does only one pass; it never reinterprets the same code unless you put it back in the input yourself.  LaTeX can do multiple passes, but a) LaTeX, and b) I've never seen five.

Comment: @user40111: Why not use `exam`?  You're entitled to your preferences, of course, and you can just say "so I can learn how to do this", but if you just want results, that's the right answer.  Otherwise, it's like saying you don't want to use TeX to write your document.

Comment: @RyanReich Perhaps you are right... I will have a closer look on the exam class if I have more time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store away the contents of the `pr` and `solution` environments and print only the former in the first pass. Then you can print automatically the stored text. Here's a way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}%

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont%
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]%
    \hfill{\normalfont(##3)}\newline}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
  \theoremindent0cm
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newtheorem{prinn}{Problem}
\newenvironment{solinn}
  {\noindent\small Solution: \ignorespaces}{\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\usepackage{environ}
\newtoks\prsoltoks
\NewEnviron{pr}[1][]{%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks\prinn}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks[#1]}%
  \fi
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\prsoltoks\BODY\endprinn}%
\showthe\prsoltoks
  \expandafter\prinn\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else[#1]\fi\BODY\endprinn
}
\NewEnviron{solution}{%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks\begin{solinn}}%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\prsoltoks\BODY\end{solinn}}%
}

\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\begin{center}\Large Solutions\end{center}
  \setcounter{prinn}{0}\the\prsoltoks}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large Problems\end{center}

\begin{pr}[2 points]
   Problem
\end{pr}

\begin{solution}
   Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{pr}
   Problem
\end{pr}

\begin{solution}
   Solution
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

The `environ` package is very useful as it gathers the environment's contents and allows to do what's wanted with it, by storing it in the macro `\BODY`. Each time a `pr` environment appears, its contents is stored in the token register `\prsoltoks`, preceded and followed by `\begin{prinn}` and `\end{prinn}`; similarly for `solution`, but the problems are also printed out.

Notice how I got the automatic printing, by hooking to `\AtEndDocument`: now also the solutions will be printed.

Notice also a different definition for the `solution` environment (which is, internally `solinn`, but it's irrelevant from a user's point of view): whenever an environment puts text at its beginning, its "begin part" should end with `\ignorespaces`. For getting a vertical space, it's better to use `\par\medskip` or even

```
\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
```

Use whatever skip you prefer, for instance `\addvspace{\bigskipamount}` or `\addvspace{3cm}`.

Comment: @user4011 See edit

Comment: I'm trying to use your code in this answer (using MiKTeX), but I keep getting the following error: `No file [document name].aux`. Apparently this error is thrown at line 51 with `\end{pr}`. Any idea why this might be happening by any chance?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I don't think it's a problem with the code, but rather with file permissions.

Answer (score 3):

During I developed a solution egreg answered :-( -- However I will show my approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}%

\usepackage{storebox}
\newcounter{problemcount}
\newsavebox\problembox
\newsavebox\solutionbox
\newenvironment{pr}{%
\refstepcounter{problemcount}
\global\setbox\problembox\vbox\bgroup%
\trivlist\item\relax%
\subsubsection*{Problem~\theproblemcount}%
}{\endtrivlist\egroup%
\copy\problembox%
}
\newenvironment{solution}{%
\global\setbox\solutionbox\vbox\bgroup
\trivlist\item\relax%
\textit{Solution:}~\ignorespaces
}{\endtrivlist\egroup%
\clearpage
\box\problembox
\box\solutionbox
\clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pr}
   Problem
\end{pr}

\begin{solution}
   Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{pr}
   Problem
\end{pr}

\begin{solution}
   Solution
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This will print two pages for each problem, though.

Comment: @egreg: I understand the question in this way.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The egreg's solution is in principle what I want, however it seems to break mystyle, see comment above.