# Problem with tikz externalize and automatic solutions

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation, tikz-external, debugging

I am using a solution environment for exercise sheets as proposed by @egreg some years ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39566/4011. However if I combine it with the tikz externalize library, it ends in an error message.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}


\newtheorem{pr}{Problem}
\newtheorem{solinn}{ad Problem}

\newtoks\prsoltoks

\NewEnviron{Solution}{%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks\begin{solinn}}%
    \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\prsoltoks\BODY\end{solinn}}%
}


\usepackage{multicol}
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\begin{center}\Large Solutions \end{center}
  \setcounter{pr}{0}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \the\prsoltoks
  \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pr}~

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{pr}

\begin{Solution}~

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{Solution}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this results in the following error message:

```
  ERROR: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/externalize_test-figure2" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{externalize_test}\input{externalize_test}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/externalize_test-figure2' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/externalize_test-figure2.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

The error messages in `tikz/externalize_test-figure2.log` is:

```
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.10.18)  18 OCT 2015 16:15
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\def\tikzexternalrealjob{externalize_test}\input{externalize_test}
(./externalize_test.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/arti
cle.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/us
r/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/te
xlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.te
x
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/
local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr
/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/usr/
local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/m
ath/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr
/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/
texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/loca
l/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/20
15/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/
texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzl
ibraryexternal.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdie
k/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzexternalshared.code.tex))
No auxiliary output files.

\w@pgfexternal@auxout=\write4
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count107
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks27
)
\c@pr=\count108
\c@solinn=\count109
\prsoltoks=\toks28
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty
Package: multicol 2015/08/19 v1.8n multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count110
\mult@box=\box37
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen151
\c@unbalance=\count111
\c@collectmore=\count112
\doublecol@number=\count113
\multicoltolerance=\count114
\multicolpretolerance=\count115
\full@width=\dimen152
\page@free=\dimen153
\premulticols=\dimen154
\postmulticols=\dimen155
\multicolsep=\skip43
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip44
\partial@page=\box38
\last@line=\box39
\maxbalancingoverflow=\dimen156
\mult@rightbox=\box40
\mult@grightbox=\box41
\mult@gfirstbox=\box42
\mult@firstbox=\box43
\@tempa=\box44
\@tempa=\box45
\@tempa=\box46
\@tempa=\box47
\@tempa=\box48
\@tempa=\box49
\@tempa=\box50
\@tempa=\box51
\@tempa=\box52
\@tempa=\box53
\@tempa=\box54
\@tempa=\box55
\@tempa=\box56
\@tempa=\box57
\@tempa=\box58
\@tempa=\box59
\@tempa=\box60
\c@columnbadness=\count116
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count117
\last@try=\dimen157
\multicolovershoot=\dimen158
\multicolundershoot=\dimen159
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box61
\colbreak@box=\box62
\mc@col@check@num=\count118
)
No file tikz/externalize_test-figure2.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/c
ontext/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count119
\scratchdimen=\dimen160
\scratchbox=\box63
\nofMPsegments=\count120
\nofMParguments=\count121
\everyMPshowfont=\toks29
\MPscratchCnt=\count122
\MPscratchDim=\dimen161
\MPnumerator=\count123
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count124
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to d
isable this.
A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to d
isable this.

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image 
was EMPTY. I tried to externalize 'tikz/externalize_test-figure2', but it seems
 there is no such image in the document!?  
   You are currently using 'mode=convert with system call'. This problem can ha
ppen if the image (or one of the images preceeding it) was declared inside of a
 \label{} (i.e. in the .aux file): 'convert with system call' has no access to 
the main aux file.
   Possible solutions in this case:
   (a) Try using 'mode=list and make',
   (b) Issue the externalization command 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error
 -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/externalize_test-figure2" "\def\tikzexte
rnalrealjob{externalize_test}\input{externalize_test}"' *manually* (also check 
the preceeding externalized images, perhaps the file name sequence is not corre
ct).
   Repeat: the resulting image was EMPTY, your attention is required .

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.50 \end{document}

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12114 strings out of 494236
 250445 string characters out of 6165751
 282228 words of memory out of 5000000
 15223 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4893 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 517 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,1n,58p,847b,101s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Any idea what's wrong here and how to fix it?

**Edit** From the comments and answers I see that it was not entirely clear that the problem is the *combination* of the "automatic solutions code" and the external library. The external library without this "automatic solution code" works just perfect.

Comment: Have you tried to remove all additional code in your example? Your code has a lot of additional stuff. Maybe that helps to see if it's a tikz problem or a problem of other packages or custom code.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I tried to simplify me example a bit. See my new code above.

Comment: What happens when you try the solutions suggested in the log? Note that the error suggests that the run to produce the image externally does not have shell escape enabled.

Comment: How do ypu compile the code? With a batch script or an editpr like Texmaker?

Comment: I compiled it with latexmk. But the same problem happens if I do just `pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex`

Comment: Can you try just a empty documentclass, pgfplots and one little picture (\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);) and nothing else?

Comment: @cfr Using list and make doesn't seem to help. Executing the mentioned command directly also doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you not just disable externalisation for the solutions? In my experience, some things work with externalisation and some don't. When they don't, it is generally most straightforward to just not externalise the ones which don't. You can switch externalisation on and off repeatedly in your document. In fact, I do this all the time for precisely this kind of reason. It is not really surprising that externalisation cannot cope with this particular kind of case, I think. After all, there is no image to include at the point when it is typeset, and later, it must input an out-of-order image.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try externalising the image and then reading it back later as part of the definition of the environments you are setting up. But this is probably more trouble than it is worth unless you are going to do this a great deal and it takes a very great deal of time to process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the content of the second image ends up overwriting the content of the third and what TikZ considers the second image, but which is actually the third image, is unavailable. That is, you get a green circle in the problems and, if you let TikZ continue to typeset the problematic image despite the error, you also get a green circle in the solutions.

Essentially, TikZ gets very, very confused about which image is which. This happens even if you give each image a specified name.

The following code compiles without error. The images in the problems are externalised. The images in the solutions are not externalised. Instead, these are typeset as usual.

Obviously this is more of a workaround than a solution, but at least it retains partial externalisation which is better than giving up on it altogether.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ffigurau/]
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newtheorem{pr}{Problem}
\newtheorem{solinn}{ad Problem}
\newtoks\prsoltoks
\NewEnviron{Solution}{%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks\begin{solinn}}%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\prsoltoks\BODY\end{solinn}}%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \clearpage
  \tikzset{external/export=false}%
  \begin{center}
    \Large Solutions
  \end{center}
  \setcounter{pr}{0}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \the\prsoltoks
  \end{multicols}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pr}~

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{pr}

\begin{Solution}~

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{Solution}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I clean up your code and just have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then it works and I get this output plus three external files:

[image]

[image]

I compiled it using a batch file looking like this:

```
pdflatex  -shell-escape  lala.tex
```

So I assume the problem lies within your additional code.

I know this is not an answer but too much for a comment.

Comment: Thanks, but that's clear and works perfectly. Sorry my mistake. Obviously I didn't make it clear in my question that it is the combination which causes the problem

Comment: Did you try my code including the automatic solution part? Did it work?

Comment: Then I can't help you. Sorry.