# A simple example on how to use shell-escape option

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape

I have got an issue when using the *moodle* package which I suspect is related to the *-shell-escape* option see [this question on TeX-exchange: error when using tikzpicture with moodle package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459835/error-when-using-tikzpicture-with-moodle-package/459839?noredirect=1#comment1156405_459839).

In my opinion one possible reason for the issue is that the *-escape-shell* option does not work well on my system. So I want try it on my device but I lack inspiration to find a very simple working example.

So please help me with an example to try on.

I use texlive 2018 on linux mint.

Comment: Just to let you know that I have the same problem with the answer as you but I have used externalize quite a few times successfully.

Comment: Hi @marmot!  can you please  explain to me how to use  externalize ?

Comment: I can't say anything beyond the manual. Can you compile [this document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273753/121799)?

Comment: I try to figure out why someones have issues and others no ?

Comment: I really do not know why. I guess the first step would be that the author of the answer give you the full set of instructions and a *complete* example. For instance, he is saying he uses `--shell-escape` with two `-` in the beginning. I always used one `-`. And then hopefully someone else will crosscheck if that works. (Not me, I go hibernating now. ;-)

Comment: @marmot yes I can compile the document you have indicated

Comment: You will receive more help if you post your MWE and compilation options here, and not in a link, as marmot suggested.

Comment: @marmot One or two hyphens is the same.

Comment: saying "it does not work well" doesn't really allow anyone to guess your problem. What error do you get?

Comment: I am sorry if I am not as clear as It would be but I have already post a question in TeX-exchange [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459835/error-when-using-tikzpicture-with-moodle-package/459839?noredirect=1#comment1156405_459839) which has been  answered but the answers have not solved my problem. I did not wish to replicate the question but if I have to I will reedit my question here.

Comment: the multi environment of  the moodle package uses environ to caption the body of the environment. That's imho not compatible with the externalization, you need to disable it inside multi.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer What is environ and how to disable it?

Comment: environ is a package, and you can't disable it. But looking a bit more closely at the code I don't think that environ is actually the problem. But moodle redefines a lot of tikz internals and seem to have broken it. Complain to the authors.

Comment: I will contact the authors. But it seems that @javadr has succeed to compile  without errors in his answer to [this question : error when using tikzpicture with moodle package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459835/error-when-using-tikzpicture-with-moodle-package/459839?noredirect=1#comment1156405_459839). So in my opinion ( and may be I am wrong) it is possible that the issue is more related to the system settings (os and texlive) than to the *moodle* package and perhaps to the two of them.

Comment: I did not mange to contact the author of the *moodle* package because the email address provided in the documentation is no longer valid