# Theorem numbering as subsections and automatic solutions

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters, exercises

I have a problem environment where the counter is coupled to the subsection counter. However this doesn't work with [automatic solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39566/4011). I tried to couple the solutions counter to the subsections as well but this doesn't produce the correct numbers for the solutions. How can I fix this. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}


\newtheorem{pr}{Problem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{solinn}{ad Problem}[subsection]

\newtoks\prsoltoks

\NewEnviron{Solution}{%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks\begin{solinn}}%
    \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\prsoltoks\BODY\end{solinn}}%
}


\usepackage{multicol}
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage
  \section{Solutions}
  \setcounter{pr}{0}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \the\prsoltoks
  \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}


\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{pr}~

 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{pr}~

 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}

\begin{pr}~

 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{pr}~

 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Instead of adding the functionality to my code above, it would be ok, to use another package which does this if it can be made to get exactly the same output format and the same syntax (`pr` and `Solution`).

I played with `exsheets` but didn't get the correct numbering. `answers` provides another syntax: solutions inside of the problems environment (I don't want to change my large existing document; just the header).

If the new package works well [together with tikz externalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39564/4011) it would be even better (but that is not a requirement for this question).

Comment: There's no `subsection` in your solution section -- and the information about the previous subsections isn't available in your `Solution` environment

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The point is that the solution should have the same number as the corresponding problem independently if I have a subsection in the solutions section or not.

Comment: If all you need is to display solutions at the end with same counters as problems we can give you other solutions.  There are packages `answers` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/answers for example and more here https://www.ctan.org/topic/exercise

Comment: Re: »I played with `exsheets` but didn't get the correct numbering.« you are a bit impatient :) I'll sent an update to CTAN today or tomorrow which enables the correct numbering (I'll answer your other question then, too)

Comment: @clemens Sorry for beeing impatient.I need it for something with a deadline (the day after tomorrow). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce my style above roughly via exsheets with correct numbering (compiled with the latest (commit 367bf7b) exsheets version from the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/src/)). I didn't manage to apply different styles to questions and solutions and also didn't see how to get the indentation as in my original post.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\AddCounterPattern[exsheets]{subsection}{sub}


\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{mystyle}{default}{
points-pre-code = [ ,
points-post-code = ) ,
join = 
{
title[r,B]number[l,B](0.333em,0pt) ;
number[r,B]points[l,B](0.333em,0pt)
} ,
attach = { main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) }
}

\NewQuSolPair{pr}[name=Problem]{Solution}[name=ad Problem]

\SetupExSheets{
question/pre-body-hook=\itshape,
solution/pre-body-hook=\itshape,
counter-within={subsection},
headings=mystyle,
points/name=Punkt/e,counter-format=se.sub.qu}

\begin{document}


\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{pr}
 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{pr}
 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}

\begin{pr}
 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{pr}
 Problem
\end{pr}
\begin{Solution}
  Solution
\end{Solution}
\newpage


\section{Solutions}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \printsolutions
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]